# How to setup custom response header in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, service-worker

I want to take my application to offline mode, and I want to register a service worker.
My files are hosted in AWS S3 and I've created worker.js in the root of my bucket. I may need to return custom header "Service-Worker-Allowed" in  response from AWS S3 for worker.js 
Currently custom headers are requiring to have x-amz-meta headers, which I can not use. Are there anyway to add that header by using Cloudfront or Cloudfare? Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 14):

You can not set custom response headers with s3 or cloudfront.

You have 2 possible workarounds when using AWS.

1. Proxy your requests. I.e. using nginx/haproxy running on ec2
2. Using `lambda@edge`.

Option 2, `lambda@edge` is a simpler solution. It is designed to run a lambda function from a cloudfront edge node. You can use lambda@edge to run custom javascript code. You can configure your code to run before a http request is sent to cloudfront or after a http response is received from cloudfront. This allows you to set custom request or response headers. See https://medium.com/@tom.cook/edge-lambda-cloudfront-custom-headers-3d134a2c18a2 for a good write-up on how to do this.

Comment: Here's another good how to: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/adding-http-security-headers-using-lambdaedge-and-amazon-cloudfront/

Answer (score 6):

In AWS S3, click on object and go to its settings, there Metadata section where you can add custom headers. Simply click on add metadata.

This can also be done programmatically while uploading data. All api supports additional metadata.

Comment: This doesn't work for custom headers. Only standard headers

Comment: The way you mentioned above is wrong; you can't add any header you like; as I mentioned earlier, all custom headers available with prefix x-amz-meta

Comment: @RezaMousavi see my answer below ... i think these days all of this is overkill

Comment: Also see AWS docs: [Using Metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata) and [PutObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html#API_PutObject_RequestSyntax)

Answer (score 5):

I think these days the answer is different with Cloudfront's [response header policies](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/creating-response-headers-policies.html)
[image]

seems like it does the right thing as shown below

[image]

Comment: That is valid only if the person is willing to use Cloudfront.

Comment: the question asks how to do it with cloudfront ... where all the other answers say "this is not possible with cloudfront"

Comment: Yes I understand, but the answer didn't specify which service is in the screenshots. Maybe it is a good idea to edit it instead of commenting, my bad.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible at the moment. S3 only allows you to add header by prefix
**x-amz-meta** and some standard header for caching.

Comment: see @hridayesh answer

Comment: @Paul , that answer is likely overkill these days

Comment: @JoranBeasley now I'm curious, why would that answer be overkill? eco-system not changed, are the new options I'm unaware off?